# Why does allocator in c++ provide specialization for type void

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

I notice that the allocator in c++ provides specialization for type void. Is there any special purpose to do this? It doesn't make sense to allocate memory for void type, right?

Comment: If you find an answer useful, it's considered good form on this site to Accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This old [Standard Librarian](http://drdobbs.com/184403759) column by Matt Austern has a fairly thorough discussion of allocators in general, including this tidbit:

> What do we do about void? Sometimes a container has to refer to void
>   pointers, and the rebind mechanism almost gives us what we need, but
>   not quite. It doesn't work, because we would need to write something
>   like malloc_allocator::pointer, and we've defined
>   malloc_allocator in such a way that instantiating it for void would be
>   illegal. It uses sizeof(T), and it refers to T&; neither is legal when
>   T is void. **The solution is as simple as the problem: specialize
>   malloc_allocator for void**, leaving out everything except the bare
>   minimum that we need for referring to void pointers.

malloc_allocator is the sample implementation that Austern uses in his example, but it holds true for the general case.

Answer (score 2):

The allocator needs to be specialized for `void` because you cannot have references to `void`.

Comment: Though still, wouldn't that only be an issue if someone actually instantiated it for `void`?

Comment: where is allocator<void> used? can you give me an example?